# Is it ok to create a large amount of classes in JavaScript for the sake of unit testing?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing

I come from a Java background in which I was applying unit tests. Unit tests are meant for an object-oriented language so to apply unit testing in JavaScript I need to create a bunch of classes. However, it seems unnatural in JavaScript to be doing that. What is your opinion on this? I mean, what if my JavaScript application will have like 50 classes, is that fine?

Answer (score 0):

Store them in a single parent Object, maybe `UnitTests` or just `Tests` so they don't end up in the global scope. Otherwise I don't see a problem with that as long as it won't make it into production code.

Comment: Actually, I'm more concerned with the production code. The unit tests I do have in a single file.

Comment: A file is one thing, a parent object another. Javascript has become quite fast within the last months, so that should not be a problem. But it does not sound optimal. Do you really need unit tests in production?

Comment: I'm not following you. 2 things: (1) What parent object are you talking about and (2) why are you concerned about unit tests making it to production, that's a separate story, the file that contains the unit tests can be filtered out during the build process.

Comment: If it can be filtered out, why worry about them? In development some 50 objects aren't a problem. As I said, JS got a lot faster.

What I am talking about is, that if you create your test objects like that `Test1 = Something.should.equal(...)` and assign each test to a single variable, they all will be added to the `window` scope, which is considered a bad practice.
Instead, if you define a `UnitTests = {}` and then add your tests like `UnitTests.test1 = Something.should ... ` you have less of a chance to run into collisions.

Comment: Umm, well, I'm using QUnit framework which provides a global test() method. I assume that it checks that such a method doesn't exist already. I didn't even think about the speed when using JavaScript in an object-oriented way but if that was a problem then I would be upset. So I guess that I should conclude that it's alright to have many JavaScript classes for the sake of unit testing? The reason that I was concerned with it is I've never seen a project that does this (uses JavaScript in an object-oriented way).